# I am not able to insert full url in Kingsoft Writer

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, kingsoft

Here is my url which i have to insert/make hyperlink of .
`http://192.168.10.183:8080/xyzadsfgrghrh//Request?Key=eform_renderer&OwnerType=Prj&OwnerID=79061&ItemType=Aci&ItemID=20032785&ActionToPerform=View&PopupMode=Y&WindowOpenOnSave=Y&ALLOWREADACCESS=Y&FromECRGetUrl=Y&GetUrlReqParams=&ParentItemId=20032785&childProcessId=qq0k5l04Gd92FFB384jODPfA93D93D`.

> The limit is of 255 characters.So how can i insert such a long url in my Kingsoft Writer ?

Comment: you can use url shortner servieces and then insert it as hyperlink

Comment: I have a dynamic url which i am fetching it from java.So how it will be possible now

Comment: in that case you might wanna use google url shortner api

Comment: can you please elaborate the steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the shortened url dynamically from google API, first go [here](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started) create your key or alternatively you can create one from [credentails page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) for authorization so that google can verify you can send the shortened url.

Here is the sample code in python as how to proceed:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=YOUR_KEY"
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload = {"longUrl": "YOUR URL"}
r = requests.post(url, headers= headers, json=payload)
```

After success you will receive response like as mentioned on google-

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "YOUR SHORTENED URL",
 "longUrl": "YOUR LONG URL"
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you warl0ck

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation so cannot upvote your answer.But i have accepted your answer above.:)